# VideoView unexpected error: the video is not playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media, android-videoview, mp4

I have a main activity that passes a String to the next activity, the next activity uses that String as a URL to open a video. However, the video won't play.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String MovieLink = (String) extras.get("video");
System.out.println(MovieLink);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(MovieLink);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

And the error given:

```
07-19 15:31:21.857: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(85): setDataSource('landscape_1003_1_m601')
07-19 15:31:21.867: ERROR/MediaPlayer(10132): error (1, -2147483648)
07-19 15:31:21.907: ERROR/MediaPlayer(10132): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-19 15:31:21.907: DEBUG/VideoView(10132): Error: 1,-2147483648
07-19 15:31:22.347: INFO/ActivityManager(126): Displayed com.?.?/.VideoPlayer: +540ms
```

Comment: Do you have any information about video format? Here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html you can find information which format is working. Also it depends on device.

Comment: the device is a Motorola Xoom, and the file itself plays fine on itself. But when intergrated in the app it doesn't work :) it's an mp4 file and I already did research on it.

Comment: Code playing video works in my emulator so I would look for the problem in maybe MovieLink - print it and look how it looks like? When I put my link in this code - it's ok. When you tell that "file itself plays fine on itself" it means that you are playing video in other player? Maybe it has additional encoding method?

Comment: I meant that if I just play the file in any player on the tablet it works, but I found out what was wrong ;) it was indeed something with the MovieLink, it only contained the name of the raw resource. I found the solution, posted below, and made it dynamic as well :)

Answer (score 2):

fixed my problem, at last!!

here's my resulting code :)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);

    Resources res = getResources();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String MovieLink = (String) extras.get("video");
    VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    String tmp = MovieLink.replace(".mp4", "");
    int movieID = res.getIdentifier(tmp, "raw", getPackageName());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + movieID);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    vd.setMediaController(mc);

    vd.setVideoURI(uri);
    vd.start();
```